# Invalid channel for service notification error even after creating custom channel

Tags: java, android, service, android-notifications, background-service

I've implemented a `startForeground()` method to start the ongoing notification which is called in `onCreate()`. There are two usages in two different classes. I'm testing on API 27 (Android 8.1)

First Usage (PictureCapturingService.java):

**onCreate()**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    context = this.getApplicationContext();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startMyOwnForeground();
    } else {
        startForeground(1234, new Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Capturing Image").setContentText("").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif).build());
    }
```

**startMyOwnForeground()**:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground() {
    String channelID = "com.example.code";
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, "Background Service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
            .setContentTitle("Capturing Image")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();

    startForeground(1234, notification);
}
```

Second Usage (VideoRecordService.java):

Gets called from `onCreate()` and `startRecord()`

**onCreate()**:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startMyOwnForeground("Sending Message");
    }
    else {
        startForeground(1234, new Builder(this).setContentTitle("Sending Message").setContentText("").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif).build());
    }
```

**startRecord()**:

```
private void startRecord() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startMyOwnForeground("Video Recording");
    } else {
        startForeground(1234, new Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Video Recording").setContentText("").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif).build());
    }
```

**startMyOwnForeground**:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground(String str) {
    String channelID = "com.example.code";
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, "Background Service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
            .setContentTitle(str)
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();

    startForeground(1234, notification);
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.raudram.barathikannamma, PID: 18871
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: Based on `channel=null`, it would appear that there is some third path where you are trying to start a foreground service with a `Notification` that has no channel.

Comment: In what Android version you are getting the above error? I am afraid that the problem is on `startForeground(1234, new Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Video Recording").setContentText("").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build());` and not the `startMyOwnForeground` method.

Comment: @madlymad I am currently testing on API 27

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir, there are only [five usages](http://prntscr.com/n8aokf) of the `startForeground` method in my whole project, and all 5 are mentioned here. Could the error be in the default method which gets called against API<26?

Comment: I am using the following logic for creating channels and notifications https://github.com/madlymad/uptime/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/madlymad/uptime/notifications/CreateNotification.java and never had a problem... The only difference I notice between the 2 is the channel naming the system may not like the "dots"

Comment: "Could the error be in the default method which gets called against API<26?" -- that probably is the `startForeground()` call that is triggering the error. I think your problem is with your icon.

Comment: @CommonsWare no go :( I created a new notification icon using a clip art from the Image Asset

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Notifications/Foreground) works. Compare your service with mine and see what else differs, and try adapting your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am an idiot, my app level gradle had `appcompat-v7:28.0.0` and `mediarouter-v7:26.0.3` which kept resulting in runtime errors. Making them both 28.0.0 solved the issue. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your icon is set to `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`. By name, that suggests that you are trying to use your app launcher icon as your notification icon. That is not a valid notification icon, though.

Use the Image Asset Wizard in Android Studio to create a dedicated notification icon — you will find a dedicated "Notification Icons" category for the "Icon Type" in the wizard. Then, switch to using that resource, instead of `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`, and see if you have better results.

Answer (score -1):

Listen, the class in which you are creating a notification channel must inherit Application class[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srFZY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndumT.jpg)

Comment: Posting an answer with code as a picture means that it's not accessible to search engines, and that no-one can cut and paste it. You should consider clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61345367/edit) on your question and adding the code as well-formatted text.

Comment: Question has been solved, the answer is mentioned in the question's comments. The reason it is not a separate answer is because the code is correct, the problem arose from mismatch in gradle file.